# Why Does "So Long" and "It's Been So Long" Have Such Different Meanings?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I feel like it's because "So Long" has come to be as a vernacular expression with a different semantic from the standard English one, but I'd like to hear more knowledgeable opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does "back off" mean something very different from "take the back off something"?  It is because "Back off" is an idiom, and you have to learn it as an idiom.

Idioms can't be understood from the meanings of the words that they are formed of.  "So long"  is an idiom.

The etymology is interesting (but not necessary to know): It seems to be borrowed from German "Adieu so lange",  (goodbye for as long as [you are gone]).  And *perhaps* influenced by Hebrew "Shalom" or Arabic "Salaam".

The variation comes because "so" can mean both "to a great extent" ("So it's been so long" means It has been a very long time)  But "so" can also mean "to the same extent"

But there is *no way* to predict this.  It is an idiom and so much be learnt.